# How diagnose cron.weekly script that doesn't run weekly

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I have a python script in the /etc/cron.weekly directory called example.py

It has the shebang line at the top of the file;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

The file permission are;

```
-rwxr-xr-x root root
```

Have I missed something, or is there a way to diagnose why it doesn't run. Maybe an error log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of .py extension in the filename.

According to cron manual:

> The  files
>          under  /etc/cron.d  do  not  need to be executable, while the files under /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.weekly and /etc/cron.monthly do, as they are run by run-parts (see
>          run-parts(8) for more information).

From run-parts manual:

> run-parts runs all the executable files named within constraints described below, found in directory directory.  Other files and directories are silently ignored.
>
> If  neither  the  --lsbsysinit  option  nor the --regex option is given then the names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case letters, ASCII digits, ASCII underscores, and
>          ASCII minus-hyphens.

So to test if your script has an acceptable name you can run the following command:

```
run-parts --test /etc/cron.weekly
```

If your script is listed in the output then your script will be called.

Comment: I guess this is a case of RTFM. Thanks.